# ASP.net Adding Multiple Table Entries to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework 6.  I am trying to add entries from inputted information into multiple tables.

This is what I have so far:

```
 protected void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (FlowerCompanyEntities flower = new FlowerCompanyEntities())
        {
         int rFlowers = 0;
            Boolean rVase = false;
            DateTime DeliveryDate = DateTime.Parse(tbDelivery.Text);
            string flowerArrangement = ddlListFlowers.SelectedValue;

            if (flowerArrangement == "f2")
            {
                rFlowers = 1;
            }
            if (flowerArrangement == "f3")
            {
                rFlowers = 2;
            }
            if (flowerArrangement == "f1")
            {
                rFlowers = 3;
            }
            if (flowerArrangement == "f4")
            {
                rFlowers = 4;
            }
            if (flowerArrangement == "f5")
            {
                rFlowers = 5;
            }

            string vase = rbList.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();


            if (vase == "NO")
            {
                rVase = false;
            }
            if (vase == "YES")
            {
                rVase = true;
            }



            Customers cust = new Customers();
            Addresses Addr = new Addresses();
            Phone Pho = new Phone();
            Delivery Del = new Delivery();
            Arrangements arr = new Arrangements();
            OrderStatus ordstat = new OrderStatus();
            Orders ord = new Orders();

            Pho.Phone1 = tbPhone.Text;
            Addr.Street = tbStreet.Text;
           Addr.City = tbCity.Text;
            Addr.States = tbState.Text;
            Addr.Zip = tbZip.Text;
            cust.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
            cust.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
             Del.DeliverDate = DeliveryDate;
           arr.FlowerID = rFlowers;
           ordstat.OrderStatus1 = tbStatus.Text;
            ord.Vase = rVase;
            ord.OrderMessage = tbOrderMessage.Text;




            try {
                flower.Phone.Add(Pho);

                flower.Addresses.Add(Addr);

                flower.Customers.Add(cust);

                flower.Delivery.Add(Del);

                flower.Arrangements.Add(arr);

                flower.OrderStatus.Add(ordstat);

                flower.Orders.Add(ord);

                flower.SaveChanges();
                Response.Redirect("Orders.aspx");
            }

            catch { }

        }
```

However, on the button click i get an exception error.  I also just realized that some of those tables -- with those entries would need the foreign key of the other tables put in.

**Question:**  How do I add all these entries to my database when there is multiple tables and foreign keys?

Comment: Add all child entries to parent entry and after that just add parent entry in DbContext

Comment: check this question, i think i had a similar problem to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087134/asp-net-help-inserting-data-into-normalized-sql-tables-best-practice